# How to create a dataset from TFRecord and .pbtxt files?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have a dataset of images which has the images in .tfrecord format and the labels in .pbtxt. I can read the first as:

```
filenames = [filename]
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
raw_dataset
```

But once I have this dataset and the labels in a .pbtxt file, how can I add the labels to the dataset or use both for training the model?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have faced the same problem and found something really helpful to tackle the tasks. Here is the link of solution for the issue:
[Link](https://github.com/roboflow-ai/tensorflow-object-detection-faster-rcnn/blob/master/Tutorial_Mobilenet.ipynb)